# Rails 4.2 dependent: :destroy problems with CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've used `dependent: :destroy` on models before with out any problem, but in rails 4.2 I'm stuck. The past uses were mainly for classic has_many belongs_to models. It almost seems that `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` is causing my problems.

Models

```
    class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :properties
        has_many :values, :through => :properties
        has_many :tags, :through => :properties

    class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :subject
      belongs_to :tag
      belongs_to :value

    class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_one :property
        has_one :subject, :through => :property
        has_one :tag, :through => :property

    class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :properties
        has_many :subjects, :through => :properties
```

My goals were to

- Deleting a Subject would delete all associated Properties and Values
- Deleting a Property would delete the associated Value, leaving Subject intact
- or, Deleting a Value would delete the associated Property, leaving Subject intact

I tried adding dependent destroy on the values line in Subject and the property line in Value. It would delete the properties, but not the values. I tried putting it on the values properties line and value line in Property and got the same results - it would not delete the Values.

I then tried `before_destroy` filter and ran into the same type of problem or a `ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR` when I tried the the model associations. I then hacked it and got it to work:

```
    # In Subject model
    before_destroy :destroy_values
    def destroy_values
        # relations does not seem to work got the Values using a new query
            #values.destroy_all
        pids = values.pluck(:id)
        Value.where(id:pids).destroy_all
    end

    # in Value model
    before_destroy :destroy_property
    def destroy_property
        property.destroy 
    end
```

Not sure what is going on, read up as much as I could on `dependent` and tried delete_all, and every other thing I saw with no joy!

Yes, it is a strange model, just playing around and tried to replicate the "Whatit?" Apple II database in rails for grins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, when your stuck going around circles, you just have to ask a question.  When you don't get an answer, you've had time to rethink the problem. I guess I didn't try all the options.

I think the problem is my not understanding default strategy of nullify. According to my goals, you can't have a value without a property and vice versa. Trying to destroy using a through association would raise the pg error. The simple solution that I apparently didn't try was to dependent destroy properties in the Subject model and dependent destroy value in the Property model.  The warning in the guide not to use dependent destroy on a `belongs_to` association may have started my circle trip. I'm still not sure I understand the warning. My guess is that when `subject.properties` is destroyed, the subject_id is set to null before the `property.value` destroy call is made, avoiding the pg error. My cleaned up models:

```
    class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :properties, dependent: :destroy
        has_many :values, :through => :properties
        has_many :tags, :through => :properties

    class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :subject
      belongs_to :tag
      belongs_to :value, dependent: :destroy

    class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_one :property
        has_one :subject, :through => :property
        has_one :tag, :through => :property
```